# return type of Either.fold() in Kotlin arrow library

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I'm learning functional programming in Kotlin using arrow library and I come across below strange behaviour of fold function of Either type (at least for me).

```
import arrow.core.*
import arrow.syntax.function.pipe

object UserService {
    fun findAge(user: String): Either<String, Option<Int>> {
       return Either.Right(Some(1))
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val anakinAge: Either<String, Option<Int>> = UserService.findAge("Anakin")
    anakinAge.fold({itLeft -> itLeft.toUpperCase()},{itRight -> itRight.fold({ 1 }, {it})}) pipe ::println
}
```

as per the arrow fold function syntax is

```
inline fun <C> fold(ifLeft: (A) -> C, ifRight: (B) -> C): C
```

if the value is Left it executes ***ifLeft*** function and returns type **C** if it's right it executes ifRight and returns a value with the same type **C**, but in my above code snippet am returning String if the value is Left and Int if the value is Right. How does it accept this syntax?

Comment: Folding a type is like defining the elimination rule for this type. In order to eliminate `Either` you need to consider the `Right` and `Left` case. Since `Either` represents computations that might fail in Kotlin/Arrow the `Left` case doesn't contain a value, hence you are meant to provide a default value, which must have the same type as `Right`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In here, `fold` finds the first common parent of the types `String` and `Int`, which is `Any`. In Kotlin, unlike Java, there are no basic types, it's all objects.

So, if you use the result to any function that doesn't take `Any`, it fails.

```
fun check(s: String): String = s

van a = anakinAge.fold({itLeft -> itLeft.toUpperCase()},{itRight -> itRight.fold({ 1 }, {it})})
check(a)
```

yields `Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but String was expected`.